# Plotting planet(comet) movement arund start in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

I am trying to create trajectory plot in matplotlib to show how planet(comet or any body with mass) moving around the star(sun). In my context it is assumed that sun is on position (0, 0). Unfortunately, there is something off in my calculation or code or maybe both, thus I cant get the final result right.

This code below producing this 
[image: result] 
Which is clearly wrong. I have tried to google and playing around with code, but still cannot achieve the expected plot.
The expected result should be 
[image: this]

These are the formulas I was using.

[image: formulas]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import cos, sin, hypot
# constants
G = 6.67
dt = 0.005
# planet
planet_m = 5.97
planet_x = 1
planet_y = 0
# star
star_m = 1.98
star_x = 0
star_y = 0
# velocities
vx = 0
vy = 8
# 
dx = 0
dy = 0
F = 0

t = 0
fxl = []
fyl = []
for i in range(1, 50):
    t += i * dt
    dx += (star_x-planet_x)
    dy += (star_y-planet_y)
    d = hypot(dx, dy)# the same as sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
    F += G * planet_x * star_m / (d**2)

    fx = cos(dx) * -F
    fy = sin(dy) * -F
    vx += fx / planet_m * t
    vy += fy / planet_m * t
    planet_x += vx * dt
    planet_y += vy * dt
    fyl.append(fx)
    fxl.append(fy)
    print(f'Position: {planet_x} {planet_y}')
    print(f'Velocities: {vx} {vy}')


plt.plot(star_x, star_y, 'yo', fxl, fyl, '-')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be adding to the force in each iteration, you should be recalculating it; `F = (...)` instead of `F += (...)`. Similarly with `t`, `dx`, and `dy`. Furthermore the new velocity should be calculated using `dt` not `t`. The latter assumes a closed solution, but orbital motion is [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think there are a lot of strange things going on in your code. I tried to fix it in a minimal way, but there's still a very big room for improvements:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import cos, sin, hypot
# constants
G = 6.67
dt = 0.0001
# planet
planet_m = 5.97
planet_x = 1
planet_y = 0
# star
star_m = 1.98
star_x = 0
star_y = 0
# velocities
vx = 0
vy = 1

pos_x = []
pos_y = []
for i in range(1, 100000):
    dx = (star_x-planet_x)
    dy = (star_y-planet_y)
    d = hypot(dx, dy)
    F = G * star_m / (d**2)

    fx = F * dx / d
    fy = F * dy / d
    vx += fx / planet_m * dt
    vy += fy / planet_m * dt

    planet_x += vx * dt
    planet_y += vy * dt
    pos_x.append(planet_x)
    pos_y.append(planet_y)

plt.plot(star_x, star_y, 'yo', pos_x, pos_y, '-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am only begginer in python and in programming in general. So, sorry for confusion.